# Issue in populating combobox using Json from postgresql in ExtJs and Servlets

Tags: json, postgresql, servlets, extjs, combobox

In my Java EE web application there is a combobox in a form panel. I tried to populate this combobox from my postgresql database using JsonReader. I am using ExtJs 3.0 and JSP & Sevlets.
This is my ExtJs code segment for combobox and JsonReader.

```
var vehicleStore = new Ext.data.Store({

proxy : new Ext.data.HttpProxy({
    url : "http://" + host + ":" + port + "/" + projectName + "/"
            + "DeliveryVehicle"
}),
reader : new Ext.data.JsonReader({
    idProperty : 'vCode',
    root : 'vehicles',
    fields : [ {
        name : 'vCode'
    }, {
        name : 'vRegNum'
    } ]
}),
autoLoad : true
});



{
        xtype : 'combo',
        name : 'include_type',
        fieldLabel : 'Delivery Vehicle',
        emptyText : 'Delivery Vehicle',
        editable : false,
        hideLabel : true,
        style : 'marginleft:10px',
        displayField : 'vRegNum',
        valueField : 'vCode',
        store : vehicleStore,
        flex : 1
    }
```

And this is my DeliveryVehicle.java servlet.

```
package com.xontworld.ornox.Geotrack;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.Statement;

import javax.servlet.ServletContext;
import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;

import com.xontworld.ornox.connection.ConnectionManager;


public class DeliveryVehicle extends HttpServlet {
private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

/**
 * @see HttpServlet#HttpServlet()
 */
public DeliveryVehicle() {
    //super();
    // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
}

@Override
public void init() throws ServletException {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.init();
}

/**
 * @see HttpServlet#doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse
 *      response)
 */
protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request,
        HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
    processRequest(request, response);
}

/**
 * @see HttpServlet#doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse
 *      response)
 */
protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request,
        HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
    processRequest(request, response);
}

protected void processRequest(HttpServletRequest request,
        HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
    response.setContentType("text/html;charset=UTF-8");
    PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();

    ServletContext context = getServletContext();

    String dbName = context.getInitParameter("ConnectionDB");
    String connectionHost = context.getInitParameter("ConnectionHost");
    String connectionUser = context.getInitParameter("ConnectionUser");
    String connectionPassword = context.getInitParameter("ConnectionPassword");
    String port = "5433";

    Statement statement = null;
    ResultSet vehicleResultSet = null;
    Connection pgConnection = null;
    String lineString = "";

    try {
        pgConnection = ConnectionManager.getPostgresConnection(
                connectionHost, connectionUser, connectionPassword,
                dbName, port);
        out.println(connectionHost+","+ connectionUser+","+ connectionPassword+","+ dbName);
        statement = pgConnection.createStatement();
        out.print(pgConnection);

        String sql = "";


        sql = "select distinct vehiclecode, registrationnumber from hoobtvehicles v WHERE v.status='1'";

        vehicleResultSet = statement.executeQuery(sql);

        String jsonData = "{'vehicles':[";

        while (vehicleResultSet.next()) {
            jsonData += "{ 'vCode' : '";
            jsonData += vehicleResultSet.getString(1).trim();
            jsonData += "', ";
            jsonData += "'vRegNum' : '";
            jsonData += vehicleResultSet.getString(2).trim();

            if (vehicleResultSet.isLast()) {
                jsonData += "' }  ";
            } else {
                jsonData += "' } , ";
            }
        }

        jsonData += "]}";
        out.print(jsonData);

    } catch (Exception e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        out.println(e.toString());
        e.printStackTrace();

    }

}

}
```

And this is my Json data.

```
{'vehicles':[{ 'vCode' : '1001', 'vRegNum' : 'XY-100-123' } , { 'vCode' : '1002', 'vRegNum' : 'GY-122-120' } , { 'vCode' : '1000000001', 'vRegNum' : 'XY-100-123' } ]}
```

The problem is it doesn't load the combobox and it doesn't even print anything in my eclipse console. And also it doesn't show any error message in firebug console. I use alert to check the size of the **vehicleStore**. It'a zero. Anyone has an idea what's going on here.

I would be much obliged if anyone please be so kind enough to explain what's wrong with my codes and how should I correct it?

Thanks a lot

Comment: setContentType in your servlet change "text/html" to "application/json"

Comment: You specified `DeliveryVehicle` method but the method body is empty. Is that normal?

Comment: yeah. If I enter url in the browser it prints all the things that I have mentioned to print.

Comment: Here the size of vehicleStore is zero. Do you have any idea what's going on here?plz